# install vsix extensions in VS 2010 shell edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying install propowertools or emacsemulation for Visual Studio shell because I need autoclose parentheses and brackets (I've used intellij idea and emacs for long time) ..when I double click the icon I get this error:

this extension can't be installed in any currently installed product

if I copy the file inside my folder 
C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions

it doesn't work neither

It's possible install this extensions inside VS shell?...I'm using VS only for learn and develop f#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the Visual Studio Shell is similarly crippled to the Express editions of VS in that you cannot install extensions of any kind.

I suppose this is Microsoft's way of motivating you to upgrade to one of their commercial editions of VS.
If you're a student, you can download Visual Studio Professional for free from [DreamSpark](http://www.dreamspark.com/).